# Selecting PDF to import data into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, xlsm

I'm trying to import data from PDF to Excel.

The code works without using the button, but when I use the command button to get the pdf file instead of hardcoding the pdf file path, it gets this error.
[image: Error Notice]

The data shows up in my query list but I still get this error.

I tried setting the worksheet, but it seems to be ineffectual.

```vb
Dim my_file As String
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

my_file = Application.GetOpenFilename()

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Page001", Formula:= _
  "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""" & my_file & """), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Page1 = Source{[Id=""Page001""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Page1, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted He" & _
  "aders"",{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", Int64.Type}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Scan Report"", type text}, {""Column14""" & _
  ", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""

With wks.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
  "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Page001;Extended Properties=""""" _
  , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
```

---

The original code would create a new worksheet each time. This started breaking after I added file selection.

This code does work, the worksheet is set to Data worksheet, so when the code is run in there the code runs properly.

Answer (score -2):

The original code would create a new worksheet each time this for some reason started breaking after I added file selection to the code.

This code does work, the worksheet is set to Data worksheet, so when the code is ran in there the code runs properly.